# Finding the expression of an implicit vector field

Tags: vector-analysis, implicit-differentiation, divergence-operator

Suppose that we have some smoth function $f: \mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and I define a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ such that
$$ \mathbf{F} (f) = \frac{ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} }{ \left\| \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right\| }
$$
Is there a way to express $\mathbf{F}$ explicitly? If not, can we express at least its divergence explicitly?

Comment: Is $\times$ supposed to denote the vector cross product? In which case are the partial derivatives vectors?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is a vector function. The idea is that it can be seen as the parametrization of a 2-manifold, but I did not mention this because I want to stick in the general case just in case it is possible.